# Cordova | 'www' is restored when 'cordova build' of 'cordova run android'

Tags: android, html, cordova, restore

Here is the tutorial which I am following.

```
http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/setup-files.html
```

I've done **1** to **4** steps in `Module 3: Setting Up the Workshop Files`. 
The problem is **number 5**. I typed the `cordova build` and `cordova run android` exactly same as prev page. The copied contents in **www** folder are restored when I type those commands.

The **index.html** prev image is fine right after copying the contents of starter-www however they restore as initial.

Here is the initial **index.html** code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

I didn't get any error but why did it restore automatically? Did i miss something?
Does anyone have same experience?

Comment: it normally regenerate only the environment specific www folder and not the main www folder. for example, if you added android then each time on cordova build it will re-generate android/assets/www

Comment: @AAhad uhm.. I can't understand yet. I modified the index.html which is in the C:\dev\plz\workshop\platforms\android\assets\www (path). Let me clear with this... All i want to do is just change the original index.html showed on the device screen. How can i follow the tutorial?

Comment: Did you make changes inside "C:\dev\plz\workshop\platforms\android\assets\www"  and then it will be re-generated again?

Comment: @AAhad I copied the contents of another folder and then pasted in the (path). Yes it re-generated again.

Answer (score 3):

If you have modified something within the platform specific `assets/www` folder then it will be re-generated on each `Cordova build`

So as you said: `C:\dev\plz\workshop\platforms\android\assets\www (path).`  If you modified any file inside this location then it will be re-generated each time.

In order to create a new project, use below command:

- **cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld**

Now it should have created a folder with name **hello**, go inside the folder

- **cd hello**

Here you can see the **www** folder that is a common place for the code. Whatever you place here will be generated for all your specified platforms. So in your case, you copy all those files inside this folder i.e. `hello/www`

[image]

After that, add your desired platform, for example:

- **cordova platform add android**

Now you can issue the build command

- **cordova build**

and to run on device. Note device should be connected already in order to work.

- **cordova run android**

[Here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) you can see full list of commands